# Get curl response and parameter in the same line

Tags: bash, curl

I have a file containing values:

> file.txt

```
value1
value2
value3
```

And I have this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
input="test.txt"
while IFS= read -r line ; do 
    curl -o /dev/null -s -w "%{http_code}\n" -u username:token "https://website.com/api/user"$line
done < "$input" > result.txt
```

At the moment this is my output:

> result.txt

```
400
200
200
```

What I really want to achieve is to get this kind of output:

> output.txt

```
value1,400
value2,200
value3,200
```

What my code is missing to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run and *capture* the output of the `curl` command using the [command substitution](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution) syntax `$(...)`.

Then, use `echo` or `printf` to show the captured output, along with the original input, in the form you want.

```
input="test.txt"
while IFS= read -r line ; do 
    res=$(curl -o /dev/null -s -w "%{http_code}\n" -u username:token "https://website.com/api/user$line")
    printf "%s\n" "$line,$res"
done < "$input" > result.txt
```

Comment: Excellent thanks for the clear and precise answer .